# Error: Uncaught (in promise): IndexedDB error: InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, private, indexeddb

When tried to work in mozilla private window throws me out due to indexedDb. How can i manage error and skip indexedDb part allow rest system to work?
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKr5E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Move database into background script and setup events between private window and background script.